# How to make JavaScript to load after page loading - tried all solutions

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I have a problem with my site - http://toppages.co.uk ( built with CakePHP framework)
I want to load the javascript after page loading is finished ( Google PageSpeed Insights suggestion), so i moved the entire JavaScript to the footer. Then, after making some tests, i found that JavaScript dones't work properly when is placed to the footer - it loads some times,but some times not.

I tried all possible solutions - first with:
 `document.onload = function..`,then tried: `<body onload="script();">` ,after that tried to load javascript asynchronously with `"async"` function - notging helps.
So far i can't find a way to make it work. Do you have an idea what couse the problem and how can i fix it ?

Comment: When you say it didn't work you don't mean jQuery didn't load, do you? It's just that some functions didin't work? If you have functions calls early in the page before footer and you load jQuery in footer, those functions won't work.

Comment: Hi Artm, and yes - i mean  jQuery didn't load sometimes.

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I moved entire JavaScript from all pages to default view file

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    // code here
});
```

Apparently in IE7 there's no good way to tell, but here's a hack, found [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domready.shtml)

```
if (document.all && !window.opera){ //Crude test for IE
//Define a "blank" external JavaScript tag
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" id="contentloadtag" defer="defer" src="javascript:void(0)"><\/script>')
  var contentloadtag=document.getElementById("contentloadtag")
  contentloadtag.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (this.readyState=="complete")
      // do stuff here
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Elzi,i tried that too ,but doesn't work. The strange thing is that JavaScript works most of the time on Firefox, but not on Chrome and IE. Also when tried: " document.addEventListener " - IE gives me an error and JavaScript doens't load at all ( i'm using IE7 of XP).

Comment: IE7? Ooof. Yeah you need `attachEvent` instead

Comment: I didn't tried that - do you think that this function will work on all browsers?

Comment: No. Why not just do an if else, detect if IE7, else do all others?

Comment: This is a good suggestion, let me try your solution and will update you soon with the results.

Comment: I would use a better qualifier for IE7 though. Try `navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE [67]\.(?!.*Trident[1-9])/)`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before and it was that at the time I was loading jQuery from google, for some reason it didn't load from google. I'm not sure if you have the same issue but what you can try is something like this, if can't load from google, then load local.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
if (!window.jQuery) {
    document.write('<script src="/script/jquery.1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes,i'm also using Google to load it. I will try to load it locally and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

The difference between onload and onready is that onload is in charge of a specific element. and onready is working on the entire page.
[window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready) 
in this case I'would recommend to add jQuery to your page and use 
`$(document).ready(function () {/*code you'd like to execute*/});`
just by inserting `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>` at the bottom of your body tag.